# How to remove all elements of one list of a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have this list of lists:

```
    List = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3],[D,4],...]
```

How to remove all elements of one list when the user inputs one of them?

For example, if the user enters `B` I want remove the list starting with 'B' leaving the output as:

```
    NewList = [[A,1],[C,3],[D,4],...]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can filter the contents of the list:

```
l = [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3],['D',4]]
to_remove = 'B'
new_l = [[a, b] for a, b in l if a != to_remove]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 1], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) out what you dont want:

```
>>> lst = [['A',1],['B',2],['C',3],['D',4]]
>>> to_remove = 'B'
>>> new_lst = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != to_remove, lst))
>>> print(new_lst)
[['A', 1], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function with one parameter , which is list :

```
List = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]

def remove_(list_1):
    word=input("Enter word ").upper()
    for index,value in enumerate(List):
        if word in value:
            del list_1[index]

    return list_1

print(remove_(List))
```

output:

```
Enter word B
[['A', 1], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]
```